# WebProperties$Resources bean missing for custom AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to implement my custom GlobalExceptionHandler class by extending AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler (default implementation is DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler class) but unable to do so as bean(stated below) is missing which is required in constructer initilization .I am not sure why this is happening as by default implemetation it is working fine and by giving my own implementation it is asking for a bean, Please help

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler{

    public GlobalExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, Resources resources, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super(errorAttributes, resources, applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(),this::formatErrorResponse);
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> formatErrorResponse(ServerRequest request){
        Map<String, Object> errorAttributesMap = getErrorAttributes(request, ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults());
        int status = (int) Optional.ofNullable(errorAttributesMap.get("status")).orElse(500);
        return ServerResponse
                .status(status)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(errorAttributesMap));
    }
}
```

And error i am getting is:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.example.userManagementSystem.demoApp.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebProperties$Resources' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebProperties$Resources' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am not sure why this is coming. PLease help!

Comment: Your class needs a `Resources resources` that is not provided, without seeing more of your application and your configuration of it, this is impossible to answer

Comment: Baeldung never updates tutorials, beware just in case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was getting the same exception when I migrated my Webflux api application from Springboot version 2.5.x to 2.6.2.

To resolve it I added a configuration class which creates a Bean for `WebProperties.Resources` as below,

```java
@Configuration
public class ResourceWebPropertiesConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebProperties.Resources resources() {
        return new WebProperties.Resources();
    }

}
```

This solved the issue. I guess something have changed in Springboot version 2.6.x

Comment: yes you are right! something have changed in springboot version 2.6.x.

Comment: that answer lacks root cause analysis - cause in case you have your own implementation of AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler then that answer is not good enough cause of the change of constructor in the abstract class since 2.6 spring-boot version 'WebProperties.Resources' ->   'WebProperties' look here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28762

Comment: this approach gives the error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'globalExceptionHandler' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/Desktop/andysierra/repo/project/components/entry-points/reactive-web/build/libs/reactive-web.jar!/co/com/company/filters/GlobalExceptionHandler.class]: Property 'messageWriters' is required

Answer (score 12):

The root of the issue is that
ResourceProperties (which is the one that was bound to spring.resources) was removed in Spring Boot 2.6 (had been deprecated since 2.4) as explained [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28762) and also in the said version [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#web-resources-configuration).

Injecting the `WebProperties` bean in your constructor and then calling `WebProperties.getResources()` at the usage point should fix your custom global exception handler as shown in the following snippet:

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler{

    // Spring boot 2.5.x 
    public GlobalExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, Resources resources, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super(errorAttributes, resources, applicationContext);
    }

    // Spring boot 2.6.0
    public GlobalExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, WebProperties webProperties, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super(errorAttributes, webProperties.getResources(), applicationContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

bro. Sorry for my English. Y can inject WebProperties. Next step y can do getResourses() from this properties. I hope that I help to you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: no problem bro and yes you are right!   :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Order(-99)
public class ExceptionHandler implements WebExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, Throwable throwable) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = serverWebExchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        JSONObject resMsg = new JSONObject();
        try {
            resMsg.put("code", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
            if(throwable instanceof CommonException){
                resMsg.put("msg", ((CommonException) throwable).getMsg());
            }else{
                log.error("system error:", throwable);
                resMsg.put("msg", CommonCode.PLATFORM_ERR_MSG);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        DataBuffer db = response.bufferFactory().wrap(resMsg.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(db));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).